# Flutter: How can i separate network and local data operations?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, data-management

If user want to register or login to application i want to fetch data from network. But if user want to work local application get data from local data. I use provider for data management by the way. Can someone give me some idea?

Comment: See [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a parent `ChangeNotifier` and mark it abstract.
2. Include in it all common member variables and declare methods
   without implementing them.
3. Now create two `ChangeNotifier` that extends the parent
4. Implement in each one the missing code for the methods in their
   parent `ChangeNotifier`
5. Use the correct child ChangeNotifier depending on the online/offline
   state

Here is an example :

```
abstract class DataManagerNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {

  List currentData;
  String uID;

  void getData();

  void changeData();
}
```

and the 2 children will be like this :

```
class OfflineDataManagerNotifier extends DataManagerNotifier {
  @override
  void changeData() {
    // TODO: implement changeData locally
  }

  @override
  void getData() {
    // TODO: implement getData locally
  }
  
}
```

and

```
class OnlineDataManagerNotifier extends DataManagerNotifier {
  @override
  void changeData() {
    // TODO: implement changeData from network
  }

  @override
  void getData() {
    // TODO: implement getData from network
  }
  
}
```

finally, use them according to the state of user

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if(isOnlineMode){
      return ChangeNotifierProvider<DataManagerNotifier>(
          create: (context) => OnlineDataManagerNotifier(),
          child: _ScreenContent()
      );
    }
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<DataManagerNotifier>(
        create: (context) => OfflineDataManagerNotifier(),
        child: _ScreenContent()
    );
  }
}
```

And don't forget to make **ChangeNotifierProvider** as `<DataManagerNotifier>`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the answer :)